# php query in database doesn't work

Tags: php, database

Hello guys i tried to add into database some values and it's not working.I tried everything but no.
What should i do? the name of the table is "credit".
Can you help me to rezolv this problem?

```
<tr>
    <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="nr" name="nr" type="text" autofocus></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="suma" name="suma" type="text" autofocus></td>   
    <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="rate" name="rate" type="text" autofocus></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="dobanda" name="dobanda" type="text" autofocus></td>    
    <td><button class="btn btn-success" value="adaugare">Adaugare credit</button></a></td>   
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>

<?php if(isset($_POST['adaugare']))
    {
        $nr=$_POST['nr'];
        $suma=$_POST['suma'];
        $rate=$_POST['rate'];
        $dobanda=$_POST['dobanda'];

        if($nr=='')
        {

            echo"<script>alert('Introdu numar')</script>";
            exit();
        }

        if($suma=='')
        {

            echo"<script>alert('Introdu suma')</script>";
            exit();
        }
        if($rate=='')
        {
            echo"<script>alert('Introdu rate')</script>";
            exit();
        }
        if($dobanda=='')
        {
            echo"<script>alert('Introdu dobanda')</script>";
            exit();
        }
        $id=$_SESSION['id'];
        $insert_credit="insert into credit VALUE ('$nr','$id','$suma','$rate','$dobanda')";
        mysqli_query($dbcon,$insert_credit);


    }
```

Comment: Your button `adaugare` is wrong, it needs a name and type of button, in this case `type="submit"`

Comment: Also your button is not embedded in a form.

Comment: error in `$insert_credit` statement please review my answer will resolve issue

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). This will also fix any pesky quoting issues you may run into.

Comment: Everyone also missed the fact about the submit button and the related conditional statement.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem exist on line `43` becuase you defined the table names but ignores column names

Instead of this

```
$insert_credit="insert into credit VALUE ('$nr','$id','$suma','$rate','$dobanda')";
```

Use the following code

```
$insert_credit="insert into credit (col_name1, col_name2, col_name3, col_name4, col_name5) VALUES ('$nr','$id','$suma','$rate','$dobanda')";
```

and replace `col_name*` with your actual column names it will resolve your issue or if you're inserting into all columns then you can use this

```
$insert_credit="insert into credit VALUES ('$nr','$id','$suma','$rate','$dobanda')";
```

Comment: You don't need to define the column names if you're inserting all of the columns. You only need to define them if you're only inserting some columns, or inserting them in a different order than the table is created with.

Comment: @aynber, I am not aware if he is inserting into all columns and he didn't provided his table structure in this case anyways i edited my answer

Comment: Exactly, so we can't assume if the OP is or isn't inserting all of the columns. So there's no guarantee this would fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few things I can see:

1) You don't seem to have a form anywhere so not sure how you are posting anything - you need to wrap your HTML in a form tag

2) You should set the button to be a submit button so you can then send the form data

Also your code is vulnerable to all sorts of nasties as you are not checking the input in any way - lookup SQL injection

Comment: *"Your SQL query is wrong - it should either be .... and VALUES but, either way, add an S to VALUE"* - `VALUE` is valid in MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html - You need to take that out, and it's misleading.

Comment: My mistake, I always assumed VALUE was for one value and VALUES for multiple. Have removed the incorrect information

Answer (score -1):

1) I can't see you establishing your    connection to the databse

2) Change your button to a submit button

3) Your SQL query has a syntax error Wich should have been displayed if not for 1.

*4) I would not use mysql
i I find it simple to use PDO and it's allso safer

Answer (score -1):

1) I can't see you establishing your    connection to the databse

2) Change your button to a submit button
    and wrap your for-tabel in a `<form></form>`

3) Your SQL query has a syntax error Wich should have been displayed if not for 1.

*4) I would not use mysql
i I find it simple to use PDO and it's allso safer